# onchange event not fire in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, dom-events

I have a web application build on asp.net, the Textbox `onchange` event not working in Chrome?  On page load I wrote this code:

```
textbox1.Attributes.Add("onchange", "SetEditDataFlag();");
```

`SetEditDataFlag()` -- it is a JavaScript function. When I browse the application in Chrome then this function is not called when I changed some value on the textbox. Its working properly in IE.

Please help me.

Comment: Could you give us a minimal example of the HTML/JavaScript that does not work?

Comment: Does it work in FireFox?

Comment: //Page load on .cs file
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
textbox1.Attributes.Add("onchange", "SetEditDataFlag();");
}

//in .aspx page

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 function SetEditDataFlagTrue() 
 {
    var hid = false;
 }
</script>

Its very simple,

Comment: @Tenaciouslmpy: In Internet Explore,its working everytime. But in FireFox and chrome is does not work properly. Suppose we have value in the text box ="apple", and we changed it to "applee", that time onchange is not fired on Firefox and Chrome, but in IE its working. Thanks

Comment: Sure it works just not in Chrome? While settings your attribute you use "SetEditDataFlag" and the JavaScript function is "SetEditDataFlagTrue". I am pointing to the word "True".

Comment: Oh btw. The OnChange event only gets fired when the textbox loses the focus. If you want to fire an event after adding/removing a character you should use OnKeyDown/OnKeyUp.

Comment: @Joop: Thanx a lot..! I am facing another problem here I have button on my .aspx page. The button click event is fire from java script. But i got a prblem in chrome the click event is not fired. 

 var btnSave = document.getElementById('ctl00_TabContainer1_TabEvaluation_cpEvaluation_btnSave');
                      if (docVal != "") {
                          btnSave.click();
                          alert("The changes are saved sucessfully!!"); 
                      }
                      
                      }

Answer (score 1):

> Thanx a lot..! I am facing another problem here I have button on my .aspx page. The button click event is fire from java script. But i got a prblem in chrome the click event is not fired. var btnSave = document.getElementById('ctl00_TabContainer1_TabEvaluation_cpEvaluation_btnSave'); if (docVal != "") { btnSave.click(); alert("The changes are saved sucessfully!!"); } }

The code you are posting isn't that much, but I will do whatever I can to push you in the right direction.

Most browses don't support that you can fire the event of a button, or other control, like "click". Better way:

```
var btnSave = document.getElementById('ctl00_TabContainer1_TabEvaluation_cpEvaluation_btnSave');
btnSave.onclick = function() { 
    if(!typeof(docVal) == "undefined" && docVal != null && docVal != "") { 
         alert("The changes are saved successfully!!"); 
    }
};
```

Hope this works for you.